# SQL: Covering index in order to select all attributes?

Tags: sql, indexing

say I have a database table of Id, Class, Name. I want to create a query where it selects all attributes if '`name' = 'John'`. Would it make sense to use a covering index in this case like this?

`Create index database_index ON database(name)`

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: A clarification, you are using the word 'database' where you mean 'table'